# Memory managment C++ when return from function

Tags: c++, memory, return

I just start learning C++ and have some question related to memory managment.

I will write only part today because i have many question and hope i understand it with your help.

Suppose i have class A:

```
typedef ... DATA; 

Class A{   
   public:
     ...(contructor, destructor);
     DATA foo(){
       create DATA;
     }

}
```

Now suppose i want return DATA to outer scope.

My questions are:

**1.how create DATA inside function foo in better way?** (examples of foo body)

a)

```
DATA a;
....action with a;
return a;
```

Questions of this way:

*1.1 what does it mean* `DATA a;`*?*

different source - different answers:

1.1 a) Object "a" was created on stack

My understanding: it means it was craeted not in heap but somewhere in memory what have quick access to resource and have LIFO structure, it local  as it created in this function's stack frame and will be destroyed when programm goes out of function scope (frame).

1.1 b) Object "a" was created in automatic memory

My understanding: Its not a stack, but will be destroyed like in case with stack.

Who are right or, where object "a" was created? What will be if DATA is std::container (e.g vector<>),
as i understand vector<> use dinamic allocation of memory (implicitly use of new operator and it means  - on heap?)? Will vector be created on heap, and will it be destroyed automaticly like in case of on stack (or in automatic memory) and i could not warried to destroy "a" and dellocate memory? If so - in case of std::containers the difference between `DATA a;` and `DATA* ptr = new DATA();`is only who responsible for  -destroy and dellocate  - me or auto?

*1.2 How "a" will be returned?*

I heard compiller knows what in case of returning local var by value *coppy constructor* will create a coppy place it on stack and calling scope will take it from there. In case of huge object i should use move semantic. For ex. in calling scope:

```
A a;
DATA b = a.foo();
```

- Is it mean to not to coppy huge object i should define move
  operator=(&& DATA)?
- What if DATA just struct (huge struct), but not a class?
- What should i do if DATA is std::container ?

Comment: This makes huge assumptions about how the compiler implements local variables.

Comment: @ tadman Thanks for your comment! It made me think about it deeper. "System V Application Binary Interface: AMD64 Architecture".describes ways to pass parameters (in p) and to return values (out v)  from function. It said way depends of how "out v " was classified. The way i assumed will only be if data to return classified as MEMORY (cost object) type  - caller will provide space for the return values and passes the adress of  this storage to reg %rdi as it were first (hidden) arg  to function. In case of (cheap object - INTEGER and POINTERS)return will use just reg of sequence %rax,rdx %).

Answer (score 2):

Lots of good questions, here's some quick answers, really you should be reading a C++ text book.

1)

```
DATA a;
```

Both answers are right because they mean the same thing. *Automatic storage* is the technically correct term, but in practise every compiler uses a stack for automatic storage. Whatever term you use `a` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

2)

```
vector<DATA> v;
```

There's a vital thing to understand here. The vector contents (the DATA objects) are created on the heap, but the vector itself is created on the stack. This means that just like `DATA a;` `v` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope. At that point all the dynamically allocated memory will be freed and so all the `DATA` objects will be destroyed as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John!
I read book now, but it goes slowly)) ,but some things i need right now. Could you answer if it be not vector<DATA> v , but vector<DATA*> v - will  i need to destroy DATA or it also will be destroyed automaticaly (vector is smart till this level ?)

Comment: Pointers are not smart at all, when a pointer is destroyed nothing at all happen to the object it is pointing at. You will need to destroy each DATA yourself in that case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm struggling to find a reference that uses the terminology in the way you are. Could you point me at a reference. Thanks

Comment: @john You appear to be correct, and I had simply always misunderstood this. Subobjects don’t have their own storage in C++, they share their containing object’s storage.